# Updating data in string with Lua

Tags: lua, openresty

There are different urls in user_data, I want to change all usernames and passwords in user_data to make them the same. Since the URL directories are different, I want to find the username and password first, starting from the end, and update it with the new username and password.

username and password I want to change: "superuser/123456"

```
johndoe/123h456 => superuser/123456
james/98c7654 => superuser/123456
robert/32165g4 => superuser/123456
```

What do you think is the surest and most accurate way to do this using match or gsub ?

```
local user_data = "http://127.0.0.1/johndoe/123h456/1, http://127.0.0.1/news/james/98c7654/1.jpg, http://127.0.0.1/data/robert/32165g4/1.dat"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one URL per string and assuming you can anchor the string on the right side (so the username/password are the last path elements), I'd try something like this: `user_data:gsub("/[^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+)$","/superuser/123456%1")`.

`$` anchors the replacement at the end of the string, `[^/]+` means one or more characters, but not `/`, and `%1` replace it with the first capture (which is a first expression in `()`).